# Class 'yii\helpers\HTMLPurifier' not found in production

Tags: yii, yii2

The error says not found in production, i think it can be because class not yet imported, or maybe file not found.

but I have already import the class with

```
use Yii;
use common\models\TbPesan;
use common\models\TbPesanSearch;
use common\models\TbPesanDest;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use common\component\BeoHelper;
use yii\helpers\HTMLPurifier;
```

and `BaseHtmlPurifier.php` and `HtmlPurifier.php` is exists in `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers`

Here is my code which use `HTMLPurifier`

```
$model2->isi_pesan = HTMLPurifier::process($model->jawaban."<br />------------ Reply --------------<br />".$model->isi_pesan);
```

but I can run action very well in my local environment and the controller code is same.

So what's wrong?

If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please, `use yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier;` instead

Comment: This answer would be better if it expanded on why this is the fix.

Comment: @chwarr maybe you can post answer too.

Answer (score 0):

you say your local environment no problem, but you deploy to the online(prodution) environment not working. please check if the prodution environment has been exists BaseHtmlPurifier.php and HtmlPurifier.php